# paxtest on Alpine Linux

Tags: alpine-linux

Last paxtest package was at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/1.9.0_package_changes_since_1.8.3.

I cannot see paxtest package in Alpine Linux packages.

If I download the paxtest tar.gz, it wont Makefile due to missing "ld".

**The question**: how to run paxtest on Alpine Linux? (purpose: to compate output with an Ubuntu install)

Comment: You need to install all build dependencies, which includes a linker (`ld` is a linker). Furthermore we have no idea where you downloaded "paxtest tar.gz" from (or even what paxtest is – there's so much more software out there than any human could ever know!), and what its build documentation is – probably the "readme" tells you what software you'll need!

Comment: Your question is vague. Can you share what version of alpine are you using, from where are you download the paxtest file, and what steps are you following to compile it?